# Why my time is not showing correct output when submitting?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, html-input

I am using the below code. Everything is fine, but when I send information it sends in 24-hour format.
How can I resolve this? Now it's showing `13:00` I want to show `1:00 PM`.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="time" value=""  id="a_time">
  <input type="button" onclick="gettime();" value="Click Here">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function gettime(){
      alert(document.getElementById("a_time").value);
    }
  </script>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: HTML 5 inputs are displayed in the user's locale, but submitted using ISO formats. Dates are sent as Y-m-d, times are H:m:s in 24-hour time, numbers use `.` as a decimal separator...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="time" value=""  id="a_time">
<input type="button" onclick="gettime();" value="Click Here">
<script type="text/javascript">
function gettime(){
    var v = document.getElementById("a_time").value;
    var r = tConvert (v);
    alert(r);
}


function tConvert (time) {

      time = time.toString ().match (/^([01]\d|2[0-3])(:)([0-5]\d)(:[0-5]\d)?$/) || [time];
    
      if (time.length > 1) {
        time = time.slice (1); 
        time[5] = +time[0] < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'; 
        time[0] = +time[0] % 12 || 12; 
      }
      return time.join (''); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### That's what you should get.

Answer to this question is that the so-called `24 hour format` is what it suppose to apply, which is named by the official as `valid time string`, You can see in the [HTML 5.2:2 section](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/infrastructure.html#valid-time-string)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach to the previous answer which uses template literal strings and makes things more concise and easier to understand.

The idea is that you need to first get the hours part of the time by itself and convert it into an integer. Next you need to write logic to check if that number is greater than 12 to check if it's PM (and also check the corner cases when the number is either `0` which is midnight or `12` which is noon). If it's midnight or noon, return 12. Past 12, take the remainder mod 12. Otherwise return the hours as they are. Attach the minutes as they are and add either AM or PM afterwards:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="time" value=""  id="a_time">
<input type="button" onclick="gettime();" value="Click Here">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function formatTime(timeStr) {
      const hours = timeStr.substring(0, 2);
      const mins = timeStr.substring(3, 5);
    
      const isTwelve = parseInt(hours) === 0 || parseInt(hours) === 12;
      const isPM = parseInt(hours) >= 12;

      return `${isTwelve ? "12" : isPM ? `0${parseInt(hours) % 12}` : hours}:${mins} ${isPM ? "PM" : "AM"}`
  }
  function gettime(){
      const formattedTime = formatTime(document.getElementById("a_time").value);
      alert(formattedTime);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```